# Алгоритм оптимального несовпадения

Tags: c, алгоритм, строки, поиск, производительность

Господа, нашел интересный (для меня) алгоритм точного поиска подстроки, который использует частотность букав. По ссылке: [Optimal mismatch algorithm description and C implementation](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node28.html#SECTION00280)

Хотел бы получить подробное объяснение по "Preprocessing phase", а именно о том, как заполняются таблицы. Желательно на русском, потому как в С не могу...

Comment: Смотри на хабре Алгоритм Кнута — Морриса — Пратта. Есть еще несколько подобных алгоритмов (Бойер-Мура; Ахо — Корасик). На Хабре есть хорошие описания с кодом.

Comment: @Vlad Chapl  КМП использует префикс-функцию, которая не связана с частотами символов. АК тоже не является родственным алгоритмом. Ближе всего БМ.